# JPA validation annotation value setting

Tags: java, validation, jpa

For JPA Validation annotations such as `@DecimalMax(value = 100.00)`, is it possible to configure the value from properties file or database?

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: java annotation does not allow it, it should be the final value

Comment: Nope. What you can do, though, is you can create a [custom validator](https://9gag.com/gag/aR7O0gM?ref=android) with whatever logic you want (including DB lookup of arbitrary data)